# Script for Google Sheets that will convert the timestamp supplied by Google Forms into 6-8 digits

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, onsubmit

The GoogleForm is a for Product Inventory.  I work for a Food Rescue nonprofit as a fulltime volunteer so I'm sorry to be so dumb.  I've made a form that records pallet info and I want to use the timestamp to generate a 6 digit number which (fingers crossed) I'll use as the 'Timestamp' between the 'text code' and '#boxesonpallet' in a namedValues installable trigger? Which I found (and am hoping I can change) as

{
'first name':['jane'], 'Timestamp':['6/7/2015 20:54:13'], 'last name': [doe]`
}

Anyway I'm hoping to get it to calculate that number onsubmit?? (also have to learn how to do that) and then use it like this ...

{
'text code':['UHTMILK'], '6 digit number':['671523'], '#boxesonpallet': [168]`
}

and then send it back to me, so I can write the code on my pallet and move onto the next one.

Obviously I'm gonna have to learn how to take the rest of the data on the Form Response Sheet and use it for a whole lot of other purposes but it's currently taking me 20 hours to inventory and fill orders and restock and I'm the only one with a forklift licence and we are moving 20 odd pallets a week through to other charitable organisations at the moment, it's nuts.

Can you guys help me?

Answer (score 1):

**datevalue to six digit code and six digit code back to datevalue**

```
function datevaluetosixdigitcode(dv) {
  const  c=["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z","A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"];
  let html="";
  let chr={};
  c.forEach(function(ch,i){chr[i]=ch;})
  let t=Math.pow(62,1);
  let ts=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
  let valueOf=new Date().valueOf();
  var dv=dv/1000||new Date().valueOf()/1000;
  let d5=Math.floor(dv/Math.pow(t,5));
  let r5=dv%Math.pow(t,5);
  let d4=Math.floor(r5/Math.pow(t,4));
  let r4=r5%Math.pow(t,4);
  let d3=Math.floor(r4/Math.pow(t,3));
  let r3=r4%Math.pow(t,3);
  let d2=Math.floor(r3/Math.pow(t,2));
  let r2=r3%Math.pow(t,2);
  let d1=Math.floor(r2/Math.pow(t,1));
  let r1=r2%Math.pow(t,1);
  let d0=Math.floor(r1/Math.pow(t,0));
  let code=Utilities.formatString('%s%s%s%s%s%s',chr[d5],chr[d4],chr[d3],chr[d2],chr[d1],chr[d0]);
  //html+=Utilities.formatString('radix:%s<br />valueOf:%s<br />TimeStamp:%s<br />Six Digit Code:%s%s%s%s%s%s<br />test: %s<br />TheOtherWay:%s',t,valueOf,ts,chr[d5],chr[d4],chr[d3],chr[d2],chr[d1],chr[d0],code,goingtheotherway(code))
  //SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html), "Display");
  return code;
}


function sixdigitcodetodatevalue(code) {
  const  c=["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z","A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"];
  var code=code||'1JIRIR';
  let idx={};
  let html="";
  c.forEach(function(chr,i){idx[chr]=i});
  let cA=code.split("").reverse();
  let valueOf=cA.reduce(function(a,c,i){
    a.total+=idx[c]*Math.pow(a.radix,i);
    return a;
  },{radix:62,total:0,valueOf:function(){return this.total*1000;}}).valueOf();
  html=Number(valueOf).toFixed(0);
  //SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html), "Display")
  return valueOf;
}

function dttesting() {
  let dt=new Date();
  let dts=Utilities.formatDate(dt, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
  let code=datevaluetosixdigitcode(dt.valueOf());
  let val=sixdigitcodetodatevalue(code);
  let fdts=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(val), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
  let html=Utilities.formatString('dts: %s<br />code: %s<br />fdts:%s ',dts,code,dts);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html), "Display");
}

function timestamptodatevalue(ts) {
  return new Date(ts).valueOf();
}
```

Testing Display:

[image]